# css hiding link mouseovers

Tags: css

I have a navigation menu where I hide three of the ten links, however the mouseover effect still displays when I mouseover the spot where the links were.  How do I get rid of this?

```
<!--example link-->
<a HREF="#"><span CLASS="store_link">Store Links</span></a>

//mouseover effects for all links
.header_nav a:hover {
    padding: 8px 8px;
    border-top: 4px solid #CC0078;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #CC0078;
}

//hiding the three links
.header_nav a span.search_link,
.header_nav a span.cat_link,
.header_nav a span.store_link {
    display: none;
}

//my attempt at hiding mouseover effects which does not work
.header_nav a:hover span.icon-search,
.header_nav a:hover span.cat_link,
.header_nav a:hover span.store_link {
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are hiding the content of the `a` tag and not the `a` tag itself:

```
.header_nav a span.search_link {display:none}
```

You would need to hide the entire tag otherwise this would still appear visible in the DOM, possibly with a class:

```
<a HREF="#" class="hidden"><span CLASS="store_link">Store Links</span></a>

// CSS  
.header_nav a.hidden {display:none}
```

Comment: or put the hover effect on the span too... ;)

Comment: @Christoph yep, although then you would have to consider how to handle older browsers that didn't support the `:hover` pseudo element on anything other than the `a` element.

Comment: well, i think you can safely drop IE6 support nowadays. All other browsers actually suport this.